# How to set time out for each W3.CSS picture slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, w3.css

I try to use " setTimeout(function,time) " but it doesn't work.

I copy some of code in w3schools.com.(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)

This is codes of W3.CSS slideshow.

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px;">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img/food/pad.jpg" 
   style="width:100%;cursor:pointer;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">

   <img class="mySlides" src="img/food/green_curry.jpeg" 
   style="width:100%;cursor: pointer;" onclick="plusDivs(1)"> 

   <img class="mySlides" src="img/food/kai.jpg" 
   style="width:100%;cursor:pointer;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">

<div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-
display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
   <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)" >&#10094;
</div>

<div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
```

This is JavaScript code.

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
   showDivs(slideIndex += n); 
}

function currentDiv(n) {
   showDivs(slideIndex = n);  
}

function showDivs(n) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
   if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
   if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";  
   }
   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
   }
   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
   }
```

Comment: Do let me know if my solution solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the working code for your problem -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
  .mySlides {
    display: none
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Slideshow Indicators</h2>
    <p>An example of using buttons to indicate how many slides there are in the slideshow, and which slide the user is currently viewing.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="w3-center">
    <div class="w3-section">
      <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button>
    </div>
    <button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button>
    <button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button>
    <button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button>
  </div>


  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
      }
      x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-red";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, setTimeout(function,time) is working fine